# Can I "intercept" the request to serve a PWA from google cloud hosting with cloud functions?

Tags: firebase, google-app-engine, google-cloud-functions, google-web-component

I use the PWA starter kit https://pwa-starter-kit.polymer-project.org/ to create websites.  I host the sites on Google App Engine because it is very easy to host with and delivers the PRPL pattern right out of the box https://pwa-starter-kit.polymer-project.org/building-and-deploying#building-for-prpl-server.

However, in my new project I am using a separate subdomain for each client.  And each client will have a different tenant id in my firebase database.  My question is: can I intercept the http request for the PWA with a cloud function and retrieve the tenant id for the client from my database based on the requested subdomain?

In the past when I hosted everything with firebase (functions and hosting) I was able to add this to the firebase.json to redirect the http request for the PWA to a firebase function I called "renderApp"

```
"rewrites": [
  {
    "source": "**",
    "function": "renderApp"
  }
```

How can I achieve this same effect while using the Google App Engine to host my PWA?  I assume there is someway, but since I don't have a firebase.json anymore I am not sure how to do it.

In short; I would like to have the tenant id baked into my PWA when I send it out to the client, but I have to look up my tenant id located in my firebase database first (based on the subdomain from the http request)

Comment: Am I correct in assuming that subdomain = tenant id?

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I have an answer for you, but also a warning at the end of this answer.

First, make sure you've set up `*.example.com` as a custom subdomain in App Engine, and `*.example.com` is configured as a `CNAME` with your DNS provider. That will route all requests to `TENANT.example.com` to your application. (I'm assuming that the subdomain represents your tenant id).

In your application, you can pull the subdomain from the [`Host`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Host) header. In nodejs, that would look something like:

```js
const host = req.get('Host');
const [ tenant, ] = host.split('.');
```

This will solve your problem, but keep in mind that you really only want to discern the tenant_id from an authenticated user. You could integrate [Identity-Aware Proxy](https://cloud.google.com/iap/) or a custom auth solution. Relying only on subdomain is a somewhat flimsy method to achieve what I think you're trying to do, and allows any client to probe for flaws that may provide access to the data of other tenants. **Make sure you're only using the subdomain for cosmetic, white-labeling purposes, and not as part of an authentication strategy.**

See also:

- [App Engine Request Headers and Responses](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/reference/request-response-headers)